# Create complex request for post method in wso2 api manger-publisher

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am new to wso2 api manager.I created my own service in that and i want to expose that service thru publisher of wso2. By using swagger its very difficult to generate the custom json request for post method.Suppose i want to create json below classes in swagger.In below classes one class contain list of other classes.Its very difficult and time consuming to generate the json for below classes in Swagger UI.

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private List<Address> address;  
    private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumber;
}

public class Address{
    private String street_name;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String country;
}

public class PhoneNumber{
    private Long mob_no;
    private String type;
}
```

Is there any alternative to generate the json in WSo2 api manager or any api which generate the json for object.

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: general syntax for json request in wso2 api manger is below e.g.name:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ''
      x-auth-type: Application & Application User
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: name
          description: Give the name of user
          type: string
          required: true
      x-throttling-tier: Unlimited                                                                   Above request is simple but for complex request its very difficult to create the request in api manger(using swagger 2.0).